# Incorrect post_type in url of taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, post-type

I have registered a custom post type **oa_location** with custom menu (using **show_in_menu**) and a taxonomy called **oa_country**. These two connected but because our CPT placed in a custom menu, there is a problem in url of  taxonomy term:

[http://localhost/demo/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=**oa_country**&tag_ID=46&**post_type=post**&wp_http_referer=demo/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=oa_country](http://localhost/demo/wp-admin/term.php?taxonomy=__oa_country__&tag_ID=46&__post_type=post__&wp_http_referer=demo/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=oa_country)

my code to register this CPT:

```
$arg = array(
  'label'        => __('Post Type', 'text_domain'),
  'description'  => __('Post Type Description', 'text_domain'),
  'labels'       => $labels,
  'show_in_menu' => 'our-agencies',
  'taxonomies'   => array('oa_country'),
);

register_post_type('oa_location');
```

the problem is about **show_in_menu**. what can i do?

Comment: To work **show_in_menu**, show_ui must be true. try adding show_ui parameter in argument.  after that flushed rewrite rules and permalinks.